# How to check the body tag if it has a class name of "single-product" using php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need an if statement that checks the body tag if it has a class name of "single-product" using php? I need to echo a function in a single product page only of woocommerce of wordpress.

This is the code that I would like to show only for single product pages that uses woocommerce.php

```
<div id="from_product_page">
  <?php 
  $recent = new WP_Query("page_id=235"); 
  while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this:--

```
$body_classes = get_body_class();
if(in_array('single-product', $body_classes))
{
    //Single product page
} else {
    //Other Page
}
```

[get_body_class()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_body_class/) will return all body classes with array...

Answer (score 0):

Example of conditioning

```
 if($your_varname == 'single-product'){  //your condition
       //your criteria
    }
```

Comment: hello, how to do the varname? Sorry, I'm still not good yet on php. I dont know if that varname can detect or pointing to the BODY TAG that I want to detect or check. Thanks Sagar for dropping by!

Comment: its a variable name in which you want check, its exist or not ? for ex. if (the_title()) contains then your criteria

Comment: I'm still confuse because the "single product" classname is automatically or should I say dynamically included on the page when viewing a single product page. Anyway thanks :(

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't detect the body tag class of the current page, but you could use javascript or jquery to detect it and then trigger an ajax call to a php.  You may be to use a client-server-client sequence.

```
<script>
if ( $('body').hasClass('single-product') ) { 
    $('#some_input').val('single-product');
}

$.getJSON( 'gAjax.php?whatever=' + $('#whatever').val(), null, function(jdata) {

var jObj = $.parseJSON(jdata);  //RETURNED DATA

...    
<script>
```

Comment: PS: PHP executes on the server side before the document DOM is created in the browser.  Remembering that helps.